# How to remove span from QTableWidget in PyQt4 , Python 2.7?

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a `QTableWidget` with some of it's cells merged together using the following command:

```
QTableView.setSpan (self, int row, int column, int rowSpan, int columnSpan)
```

This gives me something like this:

[image]

Now, I am looking for a way to restore some of the previously merged cells back into original states (original rows and columns). When I looked into the documentation, there is this command called:

```
QTableView.clearSpans (self)
```

But as far as I understand, this reset all the spans that were previously set.

Is there any way to reset the span setting of just a specific cell without affecting the other merged cells? ( For example, just resetting the span setting on row 4, column 0 without affecting the other merged cells)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to reset the span setting of **just a specific cell**
> without affecting the other merged cells? ( For example, just
> resetting the span setting on row 4, column 0 without affecting the
> other merged cells)

## How to

Just re-use the function `setSpan` to set the span of the target cell back to **1x1**.

In your example, use `setSpan(4,0,1,1)` to reset the span setting on row4, col0.

## Example

Take your image as an example. Use `setSpan(2,1,1,1)` to "*remove*" the span setting on the target cell.

[image]